# How do you pass an array into a model in a rails seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a pretty simple question:

Let's say I am trying to create a new city in a City model in the db:seed file.

I have the following code in the seeds.rb and I want to pass in multiple values into an attribute for that city's sports teams like this:

```
City.create!(city: "Chicago,IL", teams: ["Bulls", "Cubs", "Bears"])
```

However, when I run the console and do City.first, I get the following:

```
#<City id: 375, created_at: "2013-04-05 02:55:32", updated_at: "2013-04-05 02:55:32", city: "Chicago,IL", teams: "---\n- Bulls\n- Cubs\n- Bears\n-">
```

Where are all those weird characters coming from in this result? Why does this not look like the array I was intending? I have tried a number of different approaches but none has made it work like I want.

How can I successfully pass an array into this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell rails to serialize the attribute first.  You can do that by adding the following code in your model

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :teams, Array
  ...
```

Comment: Hmm I did this and redid the seed but got the same result. Am I structuring the input correctly?

Comment: delete all cities and redo the seed.  You're most probably looking at old cities :)

Comment: Nope, I made sure to do City.delete_all first and re-ran the seed, but still got the weird markup when I called City.first in the console

Comment: did you reload the console after adding the code to the model? run `reload!` on the console.  remember that any changes done to the model  is not loaded by the console after starting it.